# multiple filter array Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have the following Array and I want to filter by multiple criteria

```
primasSalud = [
    {
      nombre: 'one',
      internacional: true,
      nacional: false,
      nacionalSinReembolso: false,
      nacionalClinicasAcotadas: false
    },
    {
      nombre: 'two',
      internacional: false,
      nacional: true,
      nacionalSinReembolso: false,
      nacionalClinicasAcotadas: false
    },
    {
      nombre: 'three',
      internacional: false,
      nacional: false,
      nacionalSinReembolso: true,
      nacionalClinicasAcotadas: false
    },
    {
      nombre: 'four',
      internacional: false,
      nacional: false,
      nacionalSinReembolso: false,
      nacionalClinicasAcotadas: true
    },
    {
      nombre: 'five',
      internacional: true,
      nacional: false,
      nacionalSinReembolso: false,
      nacionalClinicasAcotadas: false
    }
  ]
```

Then I try to filter like this:

```
this.primasResult = of(this.primasSalud.filter( prima =>
   prima.internacional == true &&
   prima.nacional == false &&
   prima.nacionalSinReembolso == false &&
   prima.nacionalClinicasAcotadas == true
));
```

So I would expect to get two results, since two objects match the filter (the first and the last) but I'm not getting any results.

In other words, what I need is that it is enough that one of the conditions has TRUE for it to be taken into account.

What is the best way to solve this?

Mi html:

```
 <div class="grillaResultadosSalud p-5">
      <div class="bg-white border rounded-lg p-3" *ngFor="let prima of primasResult | async">
        <p class="lead mb-0 text-center">{{prima.nombre}}</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3oxsi5?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: But, actually, none of them match.  You are looking for `T / F / F / T` but the first is `T / F / F / F` and the last is `T / F / F / F` also.

Comment: You are right, I have not explained it well. Actually I want to filter those that at least have true. I have edited my query.

Comment: If you need just one of the conditions to be true, replace `&&` with [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR).  But that will select every object, so it's still unclear what you want.

Comment: I want the first and last object as a result. What should be the logic?

Comment: change this    `prima.nacionalClinicasAcotadas == true` to check for false.

Answer (score 0):

If you want at least one of these to be true then try -

```
this.primasResult = of(this.primasSalud.filter( prima =>    
   !(prima.internacional == false &&    
   prima.nacional == false &&    
   prima.nacionalSinReembolso == false &&    
   prima.nacionalClinicasAcotadas == false)    
));
```